# as3 flashdevelop freezes after build

Tags: actionscript-3, build, build-process, no-response

Currently my game seems to work fine, the only problem it has is the builder does not respond 8 out of 10 times. The question is why does it stop working and how can I solve it.

Here is my code.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;



    /**
     * ...
     * @author BLANK
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public var start:StartScherm = new StartScherm;
        public var button:Startbutton = new Startbutton;

        public var balletje:Ball = new Ball;
        public var player1:Player = new Player;
        public var player2:Player2 = new Player2;
        public var player3:Player3 = new Player3;
        public var player4:Player4 = new Player4;
        public var background:Background = new Background;
        public var kader:Kader = new Kader;
        public var scoreboard:Monkeys = new Monkeys;
        public var leven1:Life = new Life;
        public var leven2:Life2 = new Life2;
        public var leven3:Life3 = new Life3;
        public var leven4:Life4 = new Life4;
        public var wall1:Walls = new Walls;
        public var wall2:Wall2 = new Wall2;
        public var wall3:Wall3 = new Wall3;
        public var wall4:Wall4 = new Wall4;

        public static var KEY_LEFT1:Boolean = false;
        public static var KEY_LEFT2:Boolean = false;
        public static var KEY_LEFT3:Boolean = false;
        public static var KEY_LEFT4:Boolean = false;
        public static var KEY_RIGHT1:Boolean = false;
        public static var KEY_RIGHT2:Boolean = false;
        public static var KEY_RIGHT3:Boolean = false;
        public static var KEY_RIGHT4:Boolean = false;

        public var GAME:Boolean = false;
        public var RESET:Boolean = false;

        public var ballSpeedX:int = -3;
        public var ballSpeedY:int = -2;

        public var LIFE1:Number = 10;
        public var LIFE2:Number = 10;
        public var LIFE3:Number = 10;
        public var LIFE4:Number = 10;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);
            addChild(start);
            addChild(button);
        }

        private function gameStart():void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            if (stage) world();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, world);

        }

        private function gameReset():void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, world);
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }



        private function world(e:Event = null):void
        {
            addChild(background);
            addChild(kader);
            addChild(player1);
            addChild(player2);
            addChild(player3);
            addChild(player4);
            addChild(scoreboard);
            addChild(leven1);
            addChild(leven2);
            addChild(leven3);
            addChild(leven4);
            addChild(balletje);
        }

        private function loop(e:Event):void
        {
            //balletje.update();

            if (GAME == true)
            {
                removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
                removeChild(start);
                removeChild(button);
                gameStart();
            }

            if (RESET == true)
            {
                removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, world);
                removeChild(background);
                removeChild(kader);
                removeChild(player1);
                removeChild(player2);
                removeChild(player3);
                removeChild(player4);
                removeChild(scoreboard);
                removeChild(leven1);
                removeChild(leven2);
                removeChild(leven3);
                removeChild(leven4);
                removeChild(balletje);
                removeChild(wall1);
                removeChild(wall2);
                removeChild(wall3);
                removeChild(wall4);
                LIFE1 = 3;
                LIFE2 = 3;
                LIFE3 = 3;
                LIFE4 = 3;
                gameReset();

            }

            if (LIFE1 == 0)
            {
                removeChild(leven1);
                addChild(wall1);
            }

            if (LIFE1 == 1)
            {
                leven1.width =  10;
                leven1.height = 10;
            }

            if (LIFE1 == 2)
            {
                leven1.width =  30;
                leven1.height = 30;
            }

            if (LIFE2 == 0)
            {
                removeChild(leven2);
                addChild(wall2);
            }

            if (LIFE2 == 1)
            {
                leven2.width =  10;
                leven2.height = 10;
            }

            if (LIFE2 == 2)
            {
                leven2.width =  30;
                leven2.height = 30;
            }

            if (LIFE3 == 0)
            {
                removeChild(leven3);
                addChild(wall3);
            }

            if (LIFE3 == 1)
            {
                leven3.width =  10;
                leven3.height = 10;
            }

            if (LIFE3 == 2)
            {
                leven3.width =  30;
                leven3.height = 30;
            }

            if (LIFE4 == 0)
            {
                removeChild(leven4);
                addChild(wall4);
            }

            if (LIFE4 == 1)
            {
                leven4.width =  10;
                leven4.height = 10;
            }

            if (LIFE4 == 2)
            {
                leven4.width =  30;
                leven4.height = 30;
            }



            balletje.x += ballSpeedX; 
            balletje.y += ballSpeedY;

                    if(balletje.x <=  -350-balletje.width/2){ //check if the x position of the left side of the ball is less than or equal to the left side of the screen, which would be 0
                        balletje.x = -350-balletje.width/2; //then set the ball's x position to that point, in case it already moved off the screen
                        ballSpeedX *= -1; //and multiply the ball's x speed by -1, which will make it move right instead of left
                        LIFE2 -= 1;

                } else if(balletje.x >= 350-balletje.width/2){ //check to see the right side of the ball is touching the right boundary, which would be 550
                    balletje.x = 350-balletje.width/2; //reposition it, just in case
                    ballSpeedX *= -1; //multiply the x speed by -1 (now moving left, not right)
                    LIFE4 -= 1;

                }

                //now we do the same with the top and bottom of the screen
                if(balletje.y <= -350-balletje.height/2){ //if the y position of the top of the ball is less than or equal to the top of the screen
                    balletje.y = -350-balletje.height/2; //like we did before, set it to that y position...
                    ballSpeedY *= -1; //...and reverse its y speed so that it is now going down instead of up
                    LIFE3 -= 1;

            } else if(balletje.y >= 350-balletje.height/2){ //if the bottom of the ball is lower than the bottom of the screen
                    balletje.y = 350-balletje.height/2; //reposition it
                    ballSpeedY *= -1; //and reverse its y speed so that it is moving up now
                    LIFE1 -= 1;

            }


                if( player1.hitTestObject(balletje) == true ){
                if(ballSpeedX < 0){
                ballSpeedY *= -1;
                ballSpeedX = calculateBallAngle2(player1.x, balletje.x);

                    }
                if(ballSpeedX > 0){
                ballSpeedY *= 1;
                ballSpeedX = calculateBallAngle2(player1.x, balletje.x);
            }

            } else if(player2.hitTestObject(balletje) == true ){ 
                if(ballSpeedX > 0){
                ballSpeedX *= -1;
                ballSpeedY = calculateBallAngle(player2.y, balletje.y);

                    }
                if(ballSpeedX < 0){
                ballSpeedX *= 1;
                ballSpeedY = calculateBallAngle(player2.y, balletje.y);
            }

            } else if(player3.hitTestObject(balletje) == true ){ 
                if(ballSpeedX > 0){
                ballSpeedY *= -1;
                ballSpeedX = calculateBallAngle2(player3.x, balletje.x);

                    }
                if(ballSpeedX < 0){
                ballSpeedY *= 1;
                ballSpeedX = calculateBallAngle2(player3.x, balletje.x);
            }
            }

            else if(player4.hitTestObject(balletje) == true ){ 
                if(ballSpeedX > 0){
                ballSpeedX *= -1;
                ballSpeedY = calculateBallAngle(player4.y, balletje.y);

                }
                if(ballSpeedX < 0){
                ballSpeedX *= 1;
                ballSpeedY = calculateBallAngle(player4.y, balletje.y);
            }

            }

            if (KEY_LEFT1 == true)
            {
                player1.x -= 10;
            }

            if (KEY_LEFT2 == true)
            {
                player1.x += 10;
            }

            if (KEY_LEFT3 == true)
            {
                player3.x -= 10;
            }

            if (KEY_LEFT4 == true)
            {
                player3.x += 10;
            }

            if (KEY_RIGHT1 == true)
            {
                player2.y += 10;
            }

            if (KEY_RIGHT2 == true)
            {
                player2.y -= 10;
            }

            if (KEY_RIGHT3 == true)
            {
                player4.y += 10;
            }

            if (KEY_RIGHT4 == true)
            {
                player4.y -= 10;
            }

        }

        private function keyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            if (e.keyCode == 37)
            {
                KEY_LEFT1 = true;
            }

            if (e.keyCode == 39)
            {
                KEY_LEFT2 = true;
            }

            if (e.keyCode == 67)
            {
                KEY_LEFT3 = true;
            }

            if (e.keyCode == 86)
            {
                KEY_LEFT4 = true;
            }

            if (e.keyCode == 65)
            {
                KEY_RIGHT1 = true;
            }

            if (e.keyCode == 81)
            {
                KEY_RIGHT2 = true;
            }

            if (e.keyCode == 102)
            {
                KEY_RIGHT3 = true;
            }

            if (e.keyCode == 105)
            {
                KEY_RIGHT4 = true;
            }

            if (e.keyCode == 13)
            {
                GAME = true;
            }

            if (e.keyCode == 8)
            {
                RESET = true;
            }
        }

                private function keyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            if (e.keyCode == 37)
            {
                KEY_LEFT1 = false;
            }

            if (e.keyCode == 39)
            {
                KEY_LEFT2 = false;
            }

            if (e.keyCode == 67)
            {
                KEY_LEFT3 = false;
            }

            if (e.keyCode == 86)
            {
                KEY_LEFT4 = false;
            }

            if (e.keyCode == 65)
            {
                KEY_RIGHT1 = false;
            }

            if (e.keyCode == 81)
            {
                KEY_RIGHT2 = false;
            }

            if (e.keyCode == 102)
            {
                KEY_RIGHT3 = false;
            }

            if (e.keyCode == 105)
            {
                KEY_RIGHT4 = false;
            }

            if (e.keyCode == 13)
            {
                GAME = false;
            }

            if (e.keyCode == 8)
            {
                RESET = false;
            }
        }

        public function calculateBallAngle(paddleY:Number, ballY:Number):Number
        {
            var ySpeed:Number = 1 * ( (ballY-paddleY) / 40 );
            return ySpeed;
        }

        public function calculateBallAngle2(paddleX:Number, ballX:Number):Number
        {
            var xSpeed:Number = 1 * ( (ballX-paddleX) / 40 );
            return xSpeed;
        }


    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 8 out of 10? What's with the other two times out of 10, does the code work as intended? If yes, I suggest fix up your computer, reinstall FlashDevelop and try again. It should not be something with the code, but rather with the environment (PC's other software, etc).

Comment: The other 2 times it works untill a certain point. but on multiple pc it stops working. Mostly when removeChild is used.

Comment: About using removeChild - it's possible you remove one object twice. So, you can check if it's removed by checking `parent` property of the object being removed. If the parent is not null, `removeChild` will work. `if (theObject.parent) theObject.parent.removeChild(theObject);` <-- An universal formula, just change `theObject` to the one being referenced to remove.